# Should I put my entire project in a package, and start it by an outside script?

Tags: python, package

Should I always put my entire project in a package (i.e. the root directory is a package and contains an `__init__.py`), and start the application using an outside script? For example:

```
some_directory
        myapp
            __init__.py
            module1.py
            some_package
                __init__.py
                module2.py
        start_myapp.py
```

And start the app by `python start_myapp.py`.

If so, where should the distribution-related (e.g. `README` and `setup.py` files) go? In `myapp`? Or in `some_directory`?

Is that the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at some git hub projects for inspiration. For example here is [link to sphinx project](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx)

Sphinx has application.py located here: `sphinx/sphinx/application.py`

To me it makes sense to put it as:

`some_directory/myapp/start_myapp.py`

and then your README and setup.py goes here: 
`some_directory/README`
`some_directory/setup.py`